# typename specific arithmetic in the standard math library

Tags: c++, templates, cmath

I am just learning about templates, so I apologize if this question expresses some ignorance. I am curious if the standard math library `cmath` supports typename specific arithmetic. The library provides functions for float and double precision - `expf` vs `exp` for example - but in the documentation it says that the non-floating point functions will always cast to a double and calculate double precision regardless of the type passed. Is there anyways around this, so I can have code that is optimized to the specific typename (I do not really want to rewrite a static math library providing this support).

Comment: dont confuse C and C++, they are different langauges. C has no templates and `cmath` is the C++ variant of the C header `math.h` (ie no templates in there)

Comment: Conjecture: You can write your own specializations that call the desired version, such as a specialization of `exp` that calls `exp<float>(x)` when called with a `uint16_t` parameter. Just a conjecture since I am not sure what the C++ standard says about using reserved names like this. If that is problematic, you could certainly do it with other names, such as `MyExp` that has all the specializations you want.

Comment: " so I can have code that is optimized to the specific typename" -> Why? That probably won't result in any faster code, nor smaller data. It will result in a larger binary.

Comment: @MooingDuck I disagree. Yes, for most applications it won't be much faster, but for big data it is. When I was running test code for my application I found floating point arithmetic to be up to 20% faster than double. This has a huge impact for programs that may be running for multiple days/weeks.